# VBA Json string for Telegram bot inline keyboard

Tags: json, string, vba, bots, telegram

I am trying to send an inline keyboard to my Telegram bot from a VBA application. The two strings I am using are resulting in a HTTP error 400 Bad Request.

Does anyone know how to build up the following two lines to get a working inline Telegram Bot keyboard?

```
Public Function SendTelegramMessage(strChatID As String, strMessage As String)
Dim objHTTP As Object
Dim strPostData As String
Dim strMarkup As String

strMarkup = "{""inline_keyboard"":[[{""text"":""A"",""callback_data"":""A1""},{""text"":""B"",""callback_data"":""C1""}]]}"
strPostData = "{""chat_id"": """ & strChatID & """, ""text"": """ & strMessage & """, ""reply_markup"": """ & strMarkup & """}"

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
On Error Resume Next
objHTTP.Open "POST", gsTelegramAPIURL & gsTelegramAPIKey & "/sendMessage?", False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
objHTTP.Send (strPostData)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    If objHTTP.Status = "200" Then
        Debug.Print "HTTP POST request was succesfull"
    ElseIf objHTTP.Status = "502" Then
        Debug.Print "HTTP status: " & objHTTP.Status & ". HTTP statustext: " & objHTTP.StatusText
        Set objHTTP = Nothing
        Exit Function
    ElseIf objHTTP.Status = "400" Then
        Debug.Print "HTTP status: " & objHTTP.Status & ". HTTP statustext: " & objHTTP.StatusText
        Set objHTTP = Nothing
        Exit Function
    Else
        Debug.Print "HTTP status: " & objHTTP.Status & ". HTTP statustext: " & objHTTP.StatusText
    End If
Else
    'Unknown error, probably no internet connection.
    Debug.Print "Error Number: " & Err.Number & " Error Source: " & Err.Source & " Error Description: " & Err.description
End If
Set objHTTP = Nothing
```

End Function

Comment: Would help to post your complete code.

Comment: As you asked I have uploaded the complete function.

Comment: Does `strMarkup` really need to be quoted inside of `strPostData` ?  That would give you a json object with a nested object but that nested object would be represented as a json *string* (so it wouldn't be an object itself).  Is that what you intend?

Comment: Not necessary intending to create a string. I am simply trying to get the format correct so I know how to create one complete string of json in VBA format. In all other languages there are json libraries to create objects en parameters which lack in VBA.

Comment: In VBA you can use this library: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: I am using that library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (without the quotes around `strMarkup`):

```
 strMarkup = "{""inline_keyboard"":[[{""text"":""A"",""callback_data"":""A1""}," & _
             "{""text"":""B"",""callback_data"":""C1""}]]}"

 strPostData = "{""chat_id"": """ & strChatID & """, ""text"": """ & _
              strMessage & """, ""reply_markup"": " & strMarkup & "}"
```